# context error while passing asynctask value to mainactivity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-gridview

In my main activity if I apply this code I got error `gridviewadapter() cannot be applied,` it is problem  in context this.

```
  GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);
```

if I apply it like this :

```
public MainActivity (Context context) {
        mContext = context;

    }
      GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(mContext, R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);
```

I got this error in logcat

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.justedhak.www.i.MainActivity; no empty constructor
```

I am trying to pass asynctask arraylist value to mainactivity .. how to fix that ?

Comment: I think you should not using constructor for `MainActivity`. You could use: `GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);`

Comment: @MrNeo i tried your way and it worked you can post it as answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not using constructor for `MainActivity` class.
Kindly using:

```
GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);
```

instead of:

```
GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);
```

Answer (score 2):

remove this constructor

```
public MainActivity (Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

add this inside `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`

```
mContext = this;
```

Answer (score 2):

GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, Listitem);

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass `mContext` variable, initialize this variable like the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private final Context mContext = this;

     ... // other codes such as onCreate...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi man thanks for your answer, the above accepted answer did the work. Now i am working with styling the toolbar do you have answers for you about that? About toolbars?

Comment: I still didnt post the question, i still reading about it , once i ask the question ill tell you btw what time is at your country?

Comment: hi man do you have best result for this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197213/styling-bottom-action-icon-postion-and-background-color